# How to return array instead of object in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, sql-server-2014

I have use in model .

```
$data = DB::select('select * from users');
return $data;
```

But in controller I have got like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 10
            [Name] => Sachin
            [Gender] => M
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Id] => 12
            [Name] => Sourav
            [Gender] => M
        )
)
```

But I want Like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 10
                [Name] => Sachin
                [Gender] => M
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Id] => 12
                [Name] => Sourav
                [Gender] => M
            )
    )
```

I already tried using get() and toArray() but its giving call to unknown member function.
Anyone have an idea how to resolved this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just use the laravel standard function

```
public function testData(){
    $data = YOUR_MODEL_NAME::all()->toArray();
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

```
public function testData(){
    $data =  DB::select('select * from users');
    $data = collect($data)->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray(); 
    echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
}
```

**Output will be :**

**UPDATED:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [email] => bmc-admin@gmail.com
            [member_code] => BMC0001ADMIN
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [email] => bmc-analyst@gmail.com
            [member_code] => BMC0003ADMIN
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [email] => bmc-product-manager@gmail.com
            [member_code] => BMC0002ADMIN
        )
)
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [drewry_user_id] => 1
            [email] => bmc-admin@gmail.com
            [name] => BMC  Administrator
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => BMC-Admin
            [member_code] => BMC0001ADMIN
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 1
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-12 04:56:31
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [drewry_user_id] => 3
            [email] => bmc-analyst@gmail.com
            [name] => BMC  Analyst
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => BMC-Analyst
            [member_code] => BMC0003ADMIN
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 3
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-26 10:55:41
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [drewry_user_id] => 2
            [email] => bmc-product-manager@gmail.com
            [name] => BMC Product Manager
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => BMC-Product-Manager
            [member_code] => BMC0002ADMIN
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 2
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-14 09:09:10
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [drewry_user_id] => 4
            [email] => bmc-customer1@gmail.com
            [name] => User 1  
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => User-1
            [member_code] => BMC0004CUSTOMER1
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 4
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-27 11:31:20
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [drewry_user_id] => 5
            [email] => bmc-customer2@gmail.com
            [name] => User 2  
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => User-2
            [member_code] => BMC0004CUSTOMER2
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 4
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-18 06:34:08
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [drewry_user_id] => 6
            [email] => bmc-customer3@gmail.com
            [name] => User 3  
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => User-3
            [member_code] => BMC0004CUSTOMER3
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 4
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-18 06:35:25
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [drewry_user_id] => 7
            [email] => bmc-customer4@gmail.com
            [name] => User 4  
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => User-4
            [member_code] => BMC0004CUSTOMER4
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 4
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-18 06:35:54
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 23
            [drewry_user_id] => 8
            [email] => bmc-customer5@gmail.com
            [name] => User 5  
            [mobile] => 
            [member_name] => User-5
            [member_code] => BMC0004CUSTOMER5
            [shipper_size] => Large
            [fk_role_id] => 4
            [fk_country_id] => 
            [timezone] => Asia/Kolkata
            [status] => 1
            [created_at] => 
            [created_by] => 
            [updated_at] => 2017-07-25 15:35:46
            [updated_by] => 
            [deleted_at] => 
        )
)
```

I hope it will work to you.

Comment: I know its works with eloquent but I could not use Eloquent in my situation.so please do answer if you know how to do with DB::select

Comment: So you want it without of Eloquent ?

Comment: You will pass raw query always ?

Comment: yes I have row query. like `DB::select('my query')`

Comment: Please check my updated answer, is that work for you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150254/discussion-between-raghbendra-nayak-systematix-and-raj).

Answer (score 7):

If you just need to get raw nested arrays of data, without using Eloquent:

```
$data = DB::connection()->getPdo()
    ->query("SELECT * FROM users")
    ->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This should be much more efficient than the current accepted answer.

Comment: Accepted answer will build models and on large datasets those approaches will crash. This answer is better because on large datasets you want to work with more raw data.

Comment: performance-wise this is the only correct answer. The other answers all convert into collections first and then back into arrays. I know the OP didn't ask for the best performing solution but if you're looking to get array data instead of Eloquent data I imagine it's probably for optimization reasons, and this is a great way to do it.

Comment: however this answer will not log the query

Answer (score 2):

toArray is a model method of Eloquent, so you need to a Eloquent model, try this:

```
 User::all()->toArray();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Comment: This only returns an array of models. I guess what Raj wants is an array of array. toArray() only changes collection to array.

Comment: This converts the data to a collection and then back to an array. Huge performance loss!